# Problemas a mudar a action com o javaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou tendo o seguinte problema, estou tentando mudar a ação do formulário usando a seguinte função, o que acontece é que se a condição for falsa para qualquer uma delas o mesmo ainda tenta executar todas as outras tentando executar todas as condições.

```
function testando(resultado) {
    var nomesconsu = null;
    var nomecampo = document.getElementById("conMarPac").value;
    $.post("/comparar", function(nomescon) {
        for (i = 0; i < nomescon.length; i++) {
            if (nomecampo == nomescon[i].nome) {
                nomesconsu = nomescon[i].nome;
            }
        }
    });
    if (nomecampo !== nomesconsu && resultado === 'marcar') {
        $('#marCon').attr('action', '/profile');
        console.log(nomesconsu);
        console.log(nomecampo);
        console.log('entrou no profile');
        return;
    } else if (nomecampo === nomesconsu && resultado === 'marcar') {
        $('#marCon').attr('action', '/incon');
        console.log('entrou no incon');
        return;
    } else if (resultado === 'salvar') {
        $('#marCon').attr('action', '/salvar');

        alert("salvo");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A variável **nomesconsu** é setada com valor dentro de um código assincrono, suas condições estão sendo verificadas antes do término da requisição do (POST). Tente colocar as verificações dentro do callback da requisição POST ($.post).

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Não consegui resolver o problema ainda, Obrigado Mesmo assim

Comment: Coloque seu código no jsfiddle.net